# Python Multiprocessing speedup

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

Imagine "heavy_thinking" does some heavy calculations and takes a long time to run. At the end of the function it returns the indizes it has to write to, and the data that belongs there. The data is then written to the according position in my array.

In theory that works and improves runtime by a lot. in practice though shuffling a lot of data to and from processes takes quite some time.

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy

cores = 4


def heavy_thinking(data):

    # heavy thinking

    return data / 4, data % 4, [data, data + 1]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    calc_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(cores)
    list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    array = numpy.empty([2, 4], dtype = object)

    print array
    data = calc_pool.map(heavy_thinking, list)

    for elements in data:
        array[elements[0]][elements[1]] = elements[2]

    print array

    calc_pool.close()
```

So what other options do I have?

Comment: I might be wrong, but wouldn't one of the large culprits be how you fill the array? I can imagine that re-building a multidimensional array iteratively takes a long time.

Comment: Unless `list` (btw. do not shadow built-in names!) or `heavy_thinking()` output is huge your issue is somewhere else. IF it is huge, you still have the option to have it as a part of a shared manager ([`multiprocessing.Manager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.multiprocessing.Manager)) which will only pass changes/data requests between processes or you can use an in-memory database like [`Redis`](https://redis.io/) or [`memcached`](https://memcached.org/) and access/modify your data directly from separate processes.

Comment: @BramVanroy I'm open for suggestions! I know that I can do the heavy calculations for the contents of the array parallel. I guess there should be a more elegant solution on how to fill it though. That's what I'm asking basically. How to put the data together in the end efficiently.

Comment: @zwer List is just a bunch of paths, so all the file parsing I need to do for the calculation happens inside the processes. My output of heavy_thinking() would be 5 lists with a few thousand elements. Is it already worth implementing in-memory databases at that point?

Comment: @ManuelBurgstaller - Depends on the size of your elements. Regular regurn will go through a pickle/unpickle cycle which might be slower than an in-memory DB. Still, if `heavy_thinking()` is indeed heavy and your inputs/outputs are not that huge the time needed to exchange the data between processes should only be a fraction of the processing time. And if `heavy_thinkng()` is not that heavy then you don't need multiprocessing to begin with.

Comment: @zwer Yeah you were right, for actual execution time I'm down from 17s to 7s (for my testcase, the actual working case is much larger). But it takes my machine around 12 seconds to initialize the multiprocessing.Pool(), which, at least in my small test case ends up being worse than doing it without multiprocessing...